# storing 16 bit variable to dereferenced variable writes 32 bits

Tags: c, reference

Consider the following:

```
// main.h
struct
{
    uint16_t aChargeOption0;
    uint16_t aChargeOption1;
} oBattChargerInfo;

typedef struct CHGRRM
{
    uint16_t nRegIndex;
    uint8_t  nDataType;
    uint32_t nDataWidth;
    uint32_t nRegAddress;
    bool     IsWritable;
    bool     HasBits;
    uint32_t nBitStoreStart;
        uint32_t nBitStoreEnd;
    int  *ptrToData;
} chargerRegMap_t;

extern chargerRegMap_t charger_reg_map[];



// main.c

chargerRegMap_t charger_reg_map[] =
{
  { &oBattChargerInfo.aChargeOption0 },
  { &oBattChargerInfo.aChargeOption1 },
};




// code to store a variable to the de-referenced variable
uint16_t aFinalBuff=0x00;
aFinalBuff=buff[1]<<8;     // buff[0] and buff[1] is uint8 
aFinalBuff=aFinalBuff+buff[0];
*charger_reg_map[nRegIndex].ptrToData=aFinalBuff;
```

When I store the first variable (`charger_reg_map[0].ptrToData`  which in the first case is `oBattChargerInfo.aChargeOption0`) the 16 bit variable overwrites the adjacent variable `oBattChargerInfo.aChargeOption1`.  Other than setting each variable in my `oBattChargerInfo` structure to 32 bits each, is there another solution?  It seems strange that a dereferenced variable would work this way.

I tried *charger_reg_map[nRegIndex].ptrToData=(uint16_t)aFinalBuff;
to make clear my intention.  Didn't matter.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `*charger_reg_map[nRegIndex].ptrToData=aFinalBuff;` <- here you _dereference_ the pointer stored in ptrToData. Is that what you really want? Is it initialized correctly? You do _not_ set the struct member `ptrToData` with this statement!

Comment: `ptrToData` is an `int*` - that is, most likely a pointer to a 32-bit integer. You can't write anything of a different size from an `int` through an `int*`.

Comment: I want the structure member ptrToData to hold a reference to the variable which I may then access and assign a value to in later code.


Here's a simpler way to express the problem:

````
    uint16_t aVars[2];
    aVars[0]=0xff;
    aVars[1]=0xff;

    int *ptrToData;
    ptrToData=&aVars[0];
    *ptrToData=0xAA;

````

Is there another method I may use to reference variables programmatically?  In the past, I've never had an issue with this because they were all 32 bit.

Comment: Why not just use a pointer of the appropriate type?

Comment: @molbdnilo My data structure has variables of uint8, uint16, uint32, ect.  

For now I've changed all my structure vars to uint32, until a better solution can be found.

Answer (score 0):

If you want differently-sized variables, there is no pointer type you can use to write to all of them.

The design is a bit brittle, since you would need to know which member your pointer is pointing to, or at least its type.

I think a better option would be to do the work with `memcpy`  through a function, and add a 'size' member to `chargerRegMap_t` for sanity checking.

Something like

```
void write_data(chargerRegMap_t* map, void* data, size_t size)
{
    assert(size == map->data_size);
    memcpy(map->ptrToData, data, size);
}

/* ... */
uint16_t aFinalBuff = 0x00;
aFinalBuff = buff[1] << 8; 
aFinalBuff = aFinalBuff + buff[0];
write_data(charger_reg_map + nRegIndex, &aFinalBuff, sizeof(aFinalBuff));
```

I would probably add a macro to that as well, to eliminate `sizeof` typos and make it less tedious:

```
#define WRITE_DATA(map, data) write_data(map, &data, sizeof(data))
/* ... */
WRITE_DATA(charger_reg_map + nRegIndex, aFinalBuff);
```